# Pthread behaviour C++

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutex

I have tried a basic pthreads/mutex program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<pthread.h>

using namespace std;

pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void* PrintHello(void *t)
{
    int i = reinterpret_cast<int>(t);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    cout<<"Hello, World thread <"<<i<<">!"<<endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t threadId[5];
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
    {
        int rc = pthread_create(&threadId[i], NULL, PrintHello, reinterpret_cast<void *>(i + 1));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And I get the following output:

Execution 1:

```
Hello, World thread <1>!
Hello, World thread <2>!
Hello, World thread <3>!
Hello, World thread <4>!
Hello, World thread <4>!
Hello, World thread <5>!
```

Execution 2:

```
Hello, World thread <1>!
Hello, World thread <2>!
Hello, World thread <3>!
Hello, World thread <4>!
Hello, World thread <5>!
Hello, World thread <5>!
```

I expected there will always be five 'Hello, World!' prints as an output of this program, but I see different. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Dumb luck if you get that much, I'm afraid. `main` likely exits before any of those threads get a chance to run. You could use a loop of `pthread_join`s on the threads to make sure they get a chance to complete.

Comment: `pthread_join` worked, there's no need of using mutex now. But still, why 'Hello, World!' is getting printed more than five times is a mystery to me.

Comment: @RakeshMhasawade As the old saying goes, undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Probably you already know, but C++ has thread support in the standard lib.

Comment: Also note that on most 64-bit systems, a pointer is 8 bytes, while an int is 32 bytes. So the conversion from void* to int may generate a compiler error. On 32-bit, things may work, but to use the API right, normally you pass in an address of a value or struct into pthread_create, and in the thread, put that back into a pointer of the same type you sent in. Or even safer, copy the contents of what is pointed to to a data item owned by the thread.

Comment: @ErikAlapää It did generate a compilation error but I used the -fpermissive to change it to a warning :D

Comment: @RakeshMhasawade: Yes, I also made it compile with -fpermissive, but doing it the right way, through pointers, is much better.

Answer (score 1):

When the main thread returns from the `main` function, it makes the process exit as by calling `exit` function. According to the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exit), it flushes `stdout`:

> All open stdio(3) streams are flushed and closed.

It is possible that because you do not join your threads, the main threads flushes `stdout`, while another thread is still writing to it. Because flushing is done in `std::cout`s destructor, it does not need to use locking as normally done (as using destroyed object is undefined behavior).

Also note that `std::endl` both adds a new line character to the stream and flushes it.

So imagine the following sequence:

1. Threads 1-4 print their message and flush it.
2. Thread 5 prints its message.
3. Main thread exits and flushes the stream, this is done without holding the usual internal lock of `std::cout`.
4. Thread 5 starts flushing `std::cout`, flushing the same message again as in step #3.

Comment: Right, this explains the weird output that I get. Thanks!